# Что такое диаграмма потоков данных действий?

Tags: диаграммы, оод

*Готовлюсь к экзамену, там вопрос о диаграмме потоков данных действий. Читаю книгу [Салли Шлеер, Стефан Меллор - Объектно-ориентированный анализ: моделирование мира в состояниях](http://storage.library.opu.ua/online/books/kaf_atp/shleer_ooa.pdf), чтобы разобраться в этом вопросе. Но там все так написано, что, вообще, не понятно.*

Может кто-нибудь, пожалуйста, нормальным языком объяснить, что такое **процесс** и **диаграмма потоков данных действий**?

Из книги:

**Процесс** - фундаментальный модуль операции.
**Диаграмма потоков данных действий** обеспечивает графическое представление модулей процесса в пределах действий и взаимодействия между ними.

**P.S.** Это не относится непосредственно к написанию кода, но я не знаю, где еще спросить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Читать желательно внимательнее. Там все есть.

> ... *в ООА **задача разбивается** сначала на объекты, затем на действия, и наконец, **на процессы** внутри действия*, выдавая в нижней части этой иерархии одну однообразную диаграмму потоков данных для каждого действия. Это отличается от традиционных методик , которые предписывают последовательную декомпозицию функции (единственной) и производят многоуровневый набор диаграмм потоков данных

и

> Управление представляется на **диаграммах потоков данных** действий: явно через потоки управления, и неявно через определенные потоки данных

и

читаем про [DFD](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFD), [IDEF0](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDEF0) (пригодиться и [IDEF1](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDEF1))

Comment: Я как раз это и не понимаю =) Я понимаю, что такое объекты, действия, но что такое "процессы" внутри действия до меня не доходит. Действие же уже элементарная единица, если мы берем внутри процесс, то это же тоже действие по сути?

Comment: Из вики: "**Процесс представляет собой** преобразование входных потоков данных в выходные в соответствии с определенным алгоритмом. Физически процесс может быть реализован различными способами: это может быть подразделение организации (отдел), выполняющее обработку входных документов и выпуск отчетов, программа, аппаратно реализованное логическое устройство и т. д."

Comment: Мда, походу у меня тяжелый случай... Извини, еще раз попробую описать, что конкретно не понимаю. Действие - как я понял, это простое элементарное действие, например, "открыть шлюз". Процесс из описания выше, должен состоять из группы таких действия, но не наоборот... Почему тогда у нас процессы являются элементами действиями?

Comment: Увы, наоборот. Если брать "элементарное", то это будут скорее - операции. А тут вот так. Чтобы быть более уверенным - рекомендую нагуглить соответствующие стандарты, спецификации. Почитать что-нибудь дополнительно, например "Процессный подход к управлению" (http://www.e-reading.club/book.php?book=113011)

Comment: спасибо большое, я прочту!